# UIPageViewController and interactive animation

Tags: ios, animation, uipageviewcontroller

How can I achieve an animation that progresses with the finger movement;

e.g. transition of background color from white to black in a smooth manner (as the finger moves from 1 VC to the next).

Can it be made using UIPageViewController?

Thanks!